# RAID Failure On Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dmraid

Recently my `RAID 0` partition has stopped working. Its a "fake RAID" using `dmraid`.
When I run the command:

```
dmraid -s
ERROR: sil: wrong # of devices in RAID set "sil_bjaccdaaeibd" [1/2] on /dev/sdc
ERROR: removing inconsistent RAID set "sil_bjaccdaaeibd"
ERROR: no RAID set found
no raid sets
```

At this point Im really not sure what this means. Any ideas?

Please let me know what other information you need.

Output of lsblk

```
 NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
 sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
 ├─sda1   8:1    0 290.1G  0 part /
 ├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
 └─sda5   8:5    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
 sdc      8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk 
 └─sdc1   8:33   0 465.8G  0 part 
 sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
 sr1     11:1    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The 465 GB disk are part of my RAID0.

Comment: It means one of your disks is dead or otherwise missing.  The output of `lsblk` might provide some insight.

Comment: May be this link helps you https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidDebug

Comment: I added the output of lsblk. All my drives are showing, is there a rebuild or rescan command?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seems to be like a hardware or controller fault. Voting to close

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this one out. I simply moved the RAID card to another PCI slot, rebooted and Ubuntu was happy again. Not sure why it went goofy in the other one